# Guidelines for developing real estate property android app

Tags: android, user-interface, server

I have to start the android application related to real estate property management for rent and buy.
Please give guidelines to start the application.
I have some specific questions please suggest me best solutions for this.

1. where to store the list of property received  from the server. Property list may cross more than 400.
2. Best way to implement search and filter option.
3. Connecting with the server. How/when to connect with server.
4. Do we need to use sqlite for storing properties(Including images and details).?
5. Property Images are stored in server(BLOB format). How to deal with this image.?

What I am following:

1. API created on server using PHP code. I am using JSOn format.
2. I will get the JSOn response and I will store it in local database.
3. I am using list view to display the data which is stored in SQLIte.
4. Property details will be displayed based on the property selected in the list of property.

Please give me tips to start the application development. what are the best methods to develop this kind of application

Provide me useful resources for best UI design and android development tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depending on the number of properties that you are getting from the server will depend on how you save it. However if there is quite a few of them then i would recommend storing them in a database on your phone. There will be a number of libraries out there that will help you implement and handle queries with the SQLite database
2. I guess you could have a search page with a number of different filters, once the user seaches it then sends that query to the database and you get the matches returned to you which you then display in a list view etc
3. When you say connecting to a server do you mean just making requests to the server? If so check out libraries like Volley and Retrofit, these libraries only require a small amount of code to get up and running instead of doing it all yourself.
4. If you have a SQLite database already to store the properties then you could just add another field thats says if the item is in a wish list etc.
5. Im sure there will be ways of converting the BLOB image into a bitmap so you shouldn't have any trouble there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I know Image conversion with BLOB. My main concern is how to deal with the server results. Let say, I have searched for "XYZ" location and I got 100 results from server. Next time I will search for "ABC" location again I will get 200 properties from server. Where to store this properties .? I know SQLlite , is there any other alternative to store .? Or Sqlite is the best solution.? If we storing all the property results then it may consume more memory(I dont have memory concern).

Comment: No Problem, if it helped feel free to upvote the answer

Comment: The only other alternatives to storing is shared preferences but based on the amount of properties you have this wouldn't be useful so SQLite would most likely be the best solution for you.

Depending on how many results you have will of course depend on how much memory it takes, however, the only other alternative is to not store the properties and just show the ones the user asks for. I.e i search "XYH" i get 10 results back and if i scroll to the bottom it loads another 10. This way you don't have the memory issue, however, your at risk of users using more data to do each of the requests.

Comment: There are also other things to take into account, when the user first comes onto the app they will have to download all of the properties which will of course use there data, Also, how often do these properties update, i would presume that prices change, houses get added and taken away, these are things you will have to think about if your store the data to the phone, how will you update this information?

Comment: Yes, Every time connecting to server is not a good idea.I will go with SQLite.

Comment: Only price of the property will be changed, property details remains same. This is a good point how to remove , add or update the property.? I have to think more on this way.

Comment: Just of the top of my head one way you could do it is when the phone loads it does a request to you to get the updates properties, once the request is back it searches the DB for those particular properties and then updates them.